# How to grant my youtube-api application read-only access to many Youtube accounts?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

I'm working on application which generates reports and statistics about youtubers channels. I couldn't find in Google docs, how the Youtube User can grant read-only access from my application to his Youtube account? (I'm meant something like facebook application).

I'm a little confused how many ways of authentication are in Google API and which one should I use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you want to access private channel data, you will need to use OAuth authorization.

The way this works is that your app redirects clients to Google's authorization page, on which they can pick a YouTube channel associated with their Google account. If they are not already logged-in, they will first be asked by Google to log in (authenticate) and then proceed to the authorization page.

Once on the authorization page, they can decide to grant or refuse your application access to whatever it is your application demands access to. This is the important part: When your application redirects the user to the authorization page, it must specify one or more **scopes**.

Scopes define sets of actions that an application can perform once the user gives their permission. An application cannot perform operations that aren't within the scope of its powers. The three most important scopes of the YouTube API are:

`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube`: *Manage your YouTube account*
`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly`: *View your YouTube account*
`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload`: *Manage your YouTube videos*

That means that you can ask users to give your application read-only access to their channel by configuring your app to use the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly` scope. This is an example of what the URL that your application redirects its users to could look like:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?
scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyoutube.readonly&
access_type=offline&
redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Foauth2callback&
response_type=code&
client_id=CLIENT_ID
```

If the user accepts, your server will be given an authorization code which it can exchange for a set of access and refresh tokens. The resource server (Google, in this case) will know with which scope these tokens were originally obtained and reject any calls outside of the scope.

This is what the authorization page currently looks like:

[image: YouTube API OAuth consent screen]

For more information, please read ['Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications' on Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/server-side-web-apps).